# How do i convert a memorystream to text?

Tags: .net, stream

I am using a tcpstream and copied the data into memorystream. Now i would like to convert it to a text (UTF-8 encoded). I tried various ways and did flush() but i could not figured it out. I tried using it in combination with StreamReader with no luck (i get a empty string).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just get the data from the `MemoryStream` and decode it:

```
string decoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(theMemoryStream.ToArray());
```

It's likely that you get an empty string because you are reading from the `MemoryStream` without resetting it's position. The `ToArray` method gets all the data regardless of where the current positon is.

If it happens to be a byte array before you put it in the `MemoryStream`, you can just use that directly.

Answer (score 11):

```
using(MemoryStream ms = GetStream())
using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ms))
{
    ms.Position = 0;
    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Comment: empty string. Guffa solved it tho. I had to seek the ms to the beginning. I ended up using his Array solution.

Comment: @acidzombie Still unsure of what you mean, setting the position to 0 is the same as seeking to the beginning(as far as I read).

Comment: Yes, correct. But i wasnt seeking and didnt know i should which was the problem.